# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat for email issue

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, predicatewithformat

I am facing issue to create NSPredicate type object with predicateWithFormat method.

```
AppDelegate *appdelegateObj = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.managedObjectContext = [appdelegateObj managedObjectContext];
NSString *emailWithBackslashedAtTheRate = [email stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@" withString:@"\\@"];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestObj = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Usertable"];
NSMutableArray *dataList;

**NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email CONTAINS[c] %@",emailWithBackslashedAtTheRate]];**
[fetchRequestObj setPredicate:predicate];

@synchronized(delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator) {

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *filteredUser = (NSMutableArray *)[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestObj error:&error];
}
```

Can anybody explain, what is issue?

Comment: what is the `error` that comes back via the call to `executeFetchRequest`?

Comment: what is the format of emailWithBackslashedAtTheRate  and what's the email attribute name in your entity ?

Comment: can you log what is the issue?

Comment: Unable to parse the format string "(email=iostest1@gmail.com)"

Answer (score 2):

In Your Usertable, Field Name Email Must be string.[image]

```
 AppDelegate *coreAppDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context=[coreAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entityDecs=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserDetail" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSFetchRequest *request =[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        [request setEntity:entityDecs];
        //  NSLog(@"username = %@",mutarr);
        NSPredicate *pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email=%@)",TxtEmail];
        [request setPredicate:pred];
        NSManagedObject *matches =nil;
        NSError *error;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `NSString` method `stringWithFormat` to build format strings for use in a predicate.  Despite the similarity in name, `predicateWithFormat` and `stringWithFormat` work differently.  You should pass the correct format string directly to `predicateWithFormat`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email CONTAINS[c] %@", email];
```

(The key difference in this instance is that `predicateWithFormat` encloses the string represented by %@ in single quotes, whereas `stringWithFormat` does not.)